# No way to tell bazel to list all targets without building or testing them

Tags: bazel

Is there a way to instruct bazel to list all the targets it has found without building or testing them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`bazel query` can be used to discover targets within a bazel workspace (without building / testing them)

For example;

To find all labels in a given package:

```
bazel query //some/package:*
```

If only interested in rules, then:

```
bazel query 'kind(.*rule, //some/package:*)'
```

`//some/package:*` could be substituted for any valid label expression, eg including all descending packages, `//some/package/...`

The [bazel query docs](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/query-how-to.html) show further functions that could be used.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list targets taking into account `select` statements resolving, take a look at `bazel cquery` command.
`query` would list targets for all select options, `cquery` - only chosen ones

[Documentation with great examples](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/cquery.html)